# How to access certain bytes in a file, modify them, and output the modified file

Tags: python, arrays, binary, steganography

I am trying to access certain bytes in a file, modify them, and output the modified file.

The file is a bitmap, but that shouldn't matter as I am using `open(file, 'rb')`. When I try to access elements in the byte object, I get combinations of letters, numbers and slashes. However, when I append elements to a list, I get numbers between 0 and 127 (which is what I'm looking for).

The problem is then modifying those and changing back into the format I originally accessed from the byte object. I have been trying to figure out what it is but can't seem to find that part of what I'm looking for.

My plan is to take a slice from the start of the file, make changes, then append the untouched slice and output the file using `write(file, 'wb')`.

Any pointers? I'm hoping there's a simple casting method and I just don't know what I'm casting to.

For some context, I am trying to code an implementation of steganography using LSB. This point is the only snag as I think I've worked out everything else. This is for a university assignment and I have to do it without libraries (except pillow, which I don't think I need).

By the way, I am slicing the file using `workingSlice = imageBytes[:length]` and `endSlice = imageBytes[length:]`, which seems to be working after a quick test. `length` will be defined by how long the hidden message is (plus the header).

Some code I wrote to test this:

```
length = 10
with open("TestBMP.bmp", "rb") as image:
    imbytes = image.read()
    workingSlice = imbytes[:length]
    endSlice = imbytes[length:]
    print(workingSlice)
    byteList = []
    for i in workingSlice:
        byteList += [i]
    print(byteList)
    stringout = b""
    for i in byteList:
        stringout += bytes(i)
    print(stringout)
```

The output:

```
b'BM6\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

[66, 77, 54, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Comment: You should [edit] your question to add more details, so that they're all in one place and people don't have to read the comments to understand your question.

Comment: Accessing elements in the bytearray and casting that to integers in a list is essentially the same thing. In the first case, you see the string representation of the bytes. In the second, the actual integer values are put in the list. You should be able to change the bytearray in place and write it back to the file using `open(file, 'wb')`. Maybe you could improve the clarity of your question by including your code? Remember to include what you expect to happen, what actually happens, and full error messages if any?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't cast them to integers myself, so it seems that's happening at some point. I'll add some of my code.

Comment: "but that shouldn't matter as I am using open(file, 'rb')". Oh, but it does. With bitmap you're _mostly_ fine, because after a bunch of header bytes, you have the pixels of the image themselves. But png or jpeg, for example, encode their data in a very different. None of that byte stream is representative of what the actual pixels are and if you change one byte you can corrupt the whole thing.